# MacOS PyQt5 - Right-click icon in dock to show all open windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

The title pretty much says it all.

How can I get an app built with PyQt5 to have similar window behavior as what's shown below? Ideally, all open windows would be shown with an indicator of the window that's int the foreground.

FIJI App Icon Right-Click:

[image]

PyQt5 App Icon Right-Click (With multiple windows open):

[image]

Comment: Maybe through a custom QMenu and then using [`setAsDockMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#setAsDockMenu)?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the suggestion. I will give this a look and let you know what I find.

Comment: Ok... I've worked this out a bit more, and I think I'm quite close to figuring it out. I've added updated code to the main comment @musicamante. Would really appreciate any further feedback!

Comment: @musicamante I think I've built a pretty decent prototyped solution - would be curious to hear your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - here is a rough solution that I've developed. I still need to figure out how to remove the window items from the dock after they've been destroyed, and I want to add indicators to show whether the windows are visible or hidden. This is a good start though!

Thanks @musicamante for the `setAsDockMenu()` flag.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QAction)

import sys
import platform
    
def add_menu(mainWindow):
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        mainWindow.menuBar = MenuBar()
        mainWindow.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(mainWindow.menuBar)


class MenuBar(QMenu):
    """ Menu bar that displays the open windows on MacOS """
    menu_items = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAsDockMenu()
        self.hide()
    
    def add_window(self, window, title):
        show_action = self.addAction(title)
        show.triggered.connect(window.showNormal)
        self.menu_items[title] = show_action
        return
        
    def remove_window(self, title):
        show_action = self.menu_items.pop[title]
        self.removeAction(show_action)
        return

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, windows, dockMenu):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.title = title
        self.windows = windows
        self.dockMenu = dockMenu
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.show()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.windows.pop(self.title)
        
        if platform.system() == "Darwin":
            self.dockMenu.remove_window(self.title)
            
        event.accept()
        self.destroy()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    windows = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        c_widget = self.centralWidget()
        c_widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        
        # If using MacOS, create a menubar to view windows.
        add_menu(self)
        
        add_item = QPushButton("Add")
        add_item.clicked.connect(self.add_window)
        c_widget.layout().addWidget(add_item)
        
        print_window = QPushButton("Print Windows")
        print_window.clicked.connect(self.show_windows)
        c_widget.layout().addWidget(print_window)
        
        self.show()
        
    def add_window(self):
        title = str(len(self.windows.keys()))
        self.window = Window(title, self.windows, self.menuBar)
        self.windows[title] = self.window
        
        self.menuBar.add_window(self.window, title)
        
    def show_windows(self):
        print (self.windows.keys())
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        QApplication.closeAllWindows()
        event.accept()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The menu should not be static, but dynamic. Actions should be added or removed whenever windows are. I've never used `setAsDockMenu()`, but if it supports the [`aboutToShow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow) signal, you should use it to actually build the menu contents. Otherwise, each window should override the `closeEvent` handler and emit a signal in order to remove their related action.

Comment: @musicamante I agree - that was something I was thinking of how to implement. This doesn't seem like a great solution, but I've just created a dict of action items for the menuBar, and when the window is closed, it calls the menuBar object with it's title so that the action can be popped from the dict and then removed.

Comment: The other thing I'm curious about, @musicamte, is if you're aware of where I could find the open window icon that's shown in the first image of the original question? It would be ideal to try to add this icon to indicate which windows are opened/closed.

Comment: Did you use [`QApplication.setWindowIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#windowIcon-prop)? If it works (and it should), you could connect the [`focusChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#focusChanged) signal to that, but be aware that, from the UI perspective, that's probably not always a good idea: the dock bar icon should always be the same, and continuously changing it might be confusing to the user. Btw, does the `aboutToShow` signal work even when using `setAsDockMenu()`?

Comment: @musicamante Sorry.. clearly the comments aren't a great way for me to try to indicate what I mean. I'm not wanting to change the app icon itself - I'm wanting to add a window icon that sits beside each menu action's name on the dock. For example, in the FIJI image in the main post, to the left of '84_002.png' there is a window icon and a checkmark icon indicating that the window is selected. Any idea of how I would implement this? Thanks

Comment: Use [`menu.addAction(QIcon, text)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-1) or [`action.setIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#icon-prop). If you've set a [`windowIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop) for those windows, then `menu.addAction(window.windowIcon(), window.windowTitle())`.